# Enable UITextField to receive Arabic language and pass it to the code

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, arabic

As the title says, the UITextField works fine and I can enter Arabic characters into it, but the problem is how to let the code deal with it because every time I pass the value of the UITextField in Arabic characters, the app doesn't show the expected results .

For more details I am passing a value of a place to Google Maps URL:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&zoom=8&scale=2&markers=size:mid|color:red|amman&maptype=roadmap\&sensor=false&center=amman
```

the word `amman` is the value that i need it to be in Arabic. If I enter Arabic characters into that URL then it will work.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&zoom=5&scale=2&markers=size:mid|color:red|%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%AF&maptype=roadmap\&sensor=false&center=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86
```

`%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86` means that in Arabic, but it seems the website doesn't support it.